# CSS 3 Media Queries support for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css, media-queries

I am having troubles finding a good process to go about registering CSS3 media Queries in my website I'm creating. I've tried the css3-mediaqueries.js but that did nothing and now I have heard that Respons.js is the way to go, however I place it in after the css stylesheet(s) and check it out in IE 8 and it crashes my site every single time!

The site I have linked to I have kept the `<script src="js/libs/respond.src.js"></script>`where I have placed it yet have deleted the .js file from the server or it'll just keep crashing.

Has anyone had this experience with Respond.js and any experience with registering CSS3 media queries for their own site? I've been trying to figure this out for quite a while now and it's quite frustrating.

I appreciate any advice!

Comment: http://ambergoodwin.com/dev/js/libs/respond.min.js Is showing up as a broken link in both IE8 and Chrome.

Comment: Whoops, sorry really out of it haha long Friday. Does the script crash chrome as well when it's on the server? Can't really debug if it's not included.

Comment: Yeah. I have it under js/libs/respond.src.js and when it's uploaded to the server and I try to open it up in IE it jut keeps crashing.

Answer (score 2):

My IE crashes when I use this combination in style.css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { 
#element {}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    .element {}
}
}
```

after

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { 
#element {}
}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) and (max-width: 320px) {
    .element {}
}
```

WORKS WELL, NO CRASH IE! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue with background images set to the body in IE8. See this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/issues/83

Try using the most recent version of Respond that Scott pushed last night: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/respond.min.js, the problem should be fixed.

If that doesn't work, you could always try an approach without a polyfill by feeding IE the other screen styles in a conditional comment. This is easiest if you're using SASS or LESS, as you can import the styles into a secondary style sheet without media queries. For more info on that, check out this post: http://nicolasgallagher.com/mobile-first-css-sass-and-ie/. If you're not using a pre-processor it might not be worth the time though.

Comment: Well my site is not crashing anymore after updating to the newest version of Respond, however it doesn't seem to be doing anything because the IE browsers still don't actually "respond". IE 8 responds the best with it actually looking like a website and responding to the actual resizing of the window, and IE 6 and 7 just turn up as very blown up images of my images and none have any kind of CSS3 media query support..

I'm not sure what is going on?? I've heard this is the best script for this issue yet it doesn't work for me? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just checked the link from your first post again, but Respond doesn't seem to be on the server.